# c++ matrix overloading not working

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading

Cannot figure out what's happening.
Why is operator overloading not working in this code ?

```
class matrix
{
protected:

    int matrix1[5][5],matrix2[5][5],resultmatrix[5][5];
    int m,n,p,q,i,j,k,l;
    public: matrix()
        {
        }
        void getdata();
        //double determinat;
        matrix operator  +(matrix);
        void showmatrix();
};

    void matrix::getdata()
    {
    cout<<"\n"<<"enter no of rows for matrix1 : "<<"\n";
    cin>>m;
    cout<<"\n"<<"enter no of columns for matrix1 : "<<"\n";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"\n"<<"enter no of rows for matrix2 : "<<"\n";
    cin>>p;
    cout<<"\n"<<"enter no of columns for matrix2 : "<<"\n";
    cin>>q;

    if(m==p&&n==q)
    {
        cout<<"\n"<<"matrixes can be added"<<"\n";
    }
    else
    {
    cout<<"\n"<<"matrixes can not be added"<<"\n";
    exit(0);
    }

    cout<<'\n'<<"please provide for matrix1: "<<"\n";

    for( i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            cin>>matrix1[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout<<'\n'<<"please provide for matrix2: "<<"\n";

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            cin>>matrix2[i][j];
        }
    }

  }

    matrix matrix::operator+( matrix matrixobj)
```

{
    matrix tempmatrixobj;

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        matrixobj.resultmatrix[i][j]=
       tempmatrixobj.matrix1[i][j]+tempmatrixobj.matrix2[i][j];
    }
}
return matrixobj;
//return tempmatrixobj;
```

//  return *this;

}

```
    void matrix::showmatrix()
     {
      for(i=0;i<m;i++)
      {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            cout<<resultmatrix[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
      }

   }

     int main()
     {
       matrix matrixobj1,matrixobj2;
        matrix resultmatrix;

       matrixobj1.getdata();

       matrixobj2.getdata();

    resultmatrix=matrixobj1+matrixobj2;

    resultmatrix.showmatrix();

    return 0;
  }
```

Addition part of the code not working at all and it takes the values twice for each matrix and thens outputs some memory addresses only.

output:

enter no of rows for matrix1 :
3

enter no of columns for matrix1 :
3

enter no of rows for matrix2 :
3

enter no of columns for matrix2 :
3

matrixes can be added

please provide for matrix1:
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1

please provide for matrix2:
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1

enter no of rows for matrix1 :
2

enter no of columns for matrix1 :
2

enter no of rows for matrix2 :
2

enter no of columns for matrix2 :
2

matrixes can be added

please provide for matrix1:
1 1
1 1

please provide for matrix2:
1 1
1 1
   -1717986920     -1717986920
   -1717986920     -1717986920
   Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: The first of all, please format your code properly and clarify what does it mean 'not working'.

Comment: Please post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

The code doing the addition

```
matrixobj.resultmatrix[i][j]=tempmatrixobj.matrix1[i]   [j]+tempmatrixobj.matrix2[i][j];
```

adds values from the `tempmatrixobj`, not from the parameters to the `operator+`.